# Importing image urls/src into JavaScript module - React

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Here's my webpack.config.js file

```
{
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|jpg)$/i,
                use: [
                    "file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]",
                    {
                        loader: "image-webpack-loader",
                        options: {
                            mozjpeg: {
                                progressive: true
                            },
                            gifsicle: {
                                interlaced: false
                            },
                            optipng: {
                                optimizationLevel: 4
                            },
                            pngquant: {
                                quality: "75-90",
                                speed: 4
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
```

And here's some of my projects.js module inside my components folder

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Pexels from 'pexels_1.png';
```

but this renders out "Can't resolve 'pexels_1.png"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely incorrect path issue as this is how to reference images with react.

Try './pexels_1.png'

This is my webpack and it is for sure working.

```
{
    test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|tiff|svg)$/,
    exclude: /\.glyph.svg/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 6000,
          name: 'image/[name].[ext]',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
```

Comment: no dice. still won't compile correctly and the same error: "Can't resolve"

Comment: check out webpack snippet above

Comment: @Society43 you need to tell webpack where are these images. One option is to add [resolve alias](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias). Then you could just import `images/titties.svg`.